# How to enable logger whitelisting for backend loggers other than console in elixir?

Tags: logging, elixir

For eg in *config.exs*

```
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: :all, 
  level: :info
```

will work but

```
config :logger, :any_other,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: :all, 
  level: :info
```

Does not

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly specify `backend` for the additional loggers; for instance, for logging to files using `LoggerFileBackend`:

```
config :logger,
  backends: [
    {LoggerFileBackend, :any_other}
  ]

config :logger, :any_other,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: :all, 
  level: :info
```

Don’t forget to include the respective package into `mix`.

Comment: I have specified backend as you mentioned and it works for 
metadata: [:module, :id],
metadata_filter: [my_logger: true],
But when I want 
metadata: :all
It doesn't work for any logger other than console

Comment: I am not aware about why the _specific_ backend does not understand `metadata: :all`. This is up to the backend how to deal with `metadata` argument.